# Passing C variables to php

Tags: php, c, arguments

cCode:

```
void main(){
    printf("line1\n");
    printf("$var=2\n");
}
```

index.php

```
    exec("./cCode", $output); 
    echo $output[2];
?>
```

As you'd expect, the php outputs the string: $var=2

However, what is the simplest way of returning variables from C to become variables in php? Json encoding perhaps? Does php and/or C have any means to easily pass or convert variable name and value pairs?

Many thanks.

Comment: You can use any format which you can make both programs understand. JSON is probably a sensible choice, as there are ready made libraries in both languages to encode and decode such data already. Much easier than inventing your own format, certainly.

Comment: Unless you want to mess with complex stuff like [FFI](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ffi.php), the most obvious way is to stop thinking of variables and memory and, instead, use standard output (but you could also use files or databases).

Comment: FFI! Thanks Álvaro, that's exactly what I was looking for! What do you mean by stop thinking of variables and memory?

Comment: In modern OSes, programs don't share variables or memory, let alone programs written in different languages that don't even have the same data types. Being able to access arbitrary memory positions would kill security and cause endless crashes. That's why we have techniques to pass information around such as shell pipes, environment variables, files...